Escape Unicode characters into ASCII, and converting them back into Unicode with no loss
I'm doing a Python project where I must encode a string into ASCII to use it, and later take it back and convert it back into Unicode. The problem is that the string may contain characters like accents, which aren't in the ASCII charset. I would like to escape these in some form in my string, then take them back with no loss.
I tried poking around with .encode and .decode to no avail, and looked at some answers on this site, but none convered both the encoding and decoding. I've seen the ascii function in Python, but it has no opposite.
Note: Using JSON, like proposed in the duplicate notes, isn't what I can do in that case. I needed to be able to have pure ASCII, which can be converted back later.
2nd note: Using a byte format, also proposed in the duplicate notes, won't work either. I need a STRING in ASCII.

Just use an existing format that solved this already. JSON, for example has built-in escape mechanisms and parsers on basically all platforms. While most JSON uses UTF-8, it's simple enough to just escape everything that isn't ASCII (and in fact some implementations do that by default).

It depends on how do you use encode. I would use it with 'unicode_escape' as encoding (so ASCII + \uxxxx and \Uxxxxxxxx

@JoachimSauer without going into much detail, using JSON won't do it. I needed that string in pure ASCII.

There are many different encoding schemes for strings for various contexts, many of which encode to pure ASCII. Which of those fits your needs we have no idea…

JSON can easily be represented using "pure ASCII", so I don't understand what your restriction is. It seems you have some additional restrictions on top of "pure ASCII" that you don't make explicit.

encode and decode work well, its just getting the sequeces right: Posisble combinations: 1. Encoding using unicode-escape codec to escape and round-trip string
2. Use ASCII codec and use xmlcharrefreplace for error handling, and use html.unescape() to round-trip string
3. Use ASCII codec and use backslashreplace or namereplace for error handling, and use unicode-escape' codec to round-trip string

I would use urllib.parse.quote and urllib.parse.unquote for that purpose, simple example:
import urllib.parse
text_with_accent = "El Niño"
ascii_text = urllib.parse.quote(text_with_accent)
print(ascii_text)  # El%20Ni%C3%B1o
print(ascii_text.isascii())  # True
original_text = urllib.parse.unquote(ascii_text)
print(text_with_accent==original_text)  # True

urllib.parse is part of standard library so you do not need installing anything beyond python itself.
